# IF statement on LTspice

Tags: ltspice

I would like to create a variable resistor as following:

```
R2=1 if i(R2)<1
R2=2 if 1<i(R2)<10
R2=3 if i(R2)>10
```

I know that the syntax is:

```
R=if(condition,valueiftrue,valueiffalse)
```

What if I have three intervals?

The .asc file and the IF statement law is also shown below.

What is the correct syntax to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Then you can either

1. Create a B source with the conditional statements and an additional signal (which is useful for debugging)
2. Nest the `if` statements

   `if(condition,valueiftrue,if(condition,valueiftrue,valueiffalse))`